# Delete comment from database and view Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I'm new to Rails so please be easy on me.

I am using the [Commontator Gem](https://github.com/lml/commontator) to enable comments on my rails app. The problem is that when I delete my comment, instead of vanishing completely (which is what I am looking for), the deleted comment still shows in my view like so " comment deleted by 'usename' ". I figured I need to create a delete route for my comments. At the moment output of rake routes are:

```
Routes for Commontator::Engine:
    delete_comment PUT   /comments/:id/delete(.:format)             commontator/comments#delete
  undelete_comment PUT   /comments/:id/undelete(.:format)           commontator/comments#undelete
```

**comment model**

```
def can_be_deleted_by?(user)
      mod_perm = thread.config.moderator_permissions.to_sym
      return true if thread.can_be_edited_by?(user) &&\
                     (mod_perm == :e ||\
                       mod_perm == :d)
      comment_del = thread.config.comment_deletion.to_sym
      !thread.is_closed? && (!is_deleted? || editor == user) &&\
      user == creator && comment_del != :n &&\
      (is_latest? || comment_del == :a) &&\
      thread.can_be_read_by?(user)
    end
```

Here is the method for deleting comments in the **comments controller**

```
def delete
      security_transgression_unless @comment.can_be_deleted_by?(@user)

      @comment.errors.add(:base, t('commontator.comment.errors.already_deleted')) \
        unless @comment.delete_by(@user)

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @thread }
        format.js { render :delete }
      end
    end
```

What are the steps I need to implement for comments to be completely deleted from the database ?

Comment: Apart from that atrocious `can_be_deleted_by?` method, you're code isn't that bad. You should stop breaking up lines with backslash. Just surround in blocks. It's more readable. The gem you are using isn't very well documented, either. If you want to just delete the comment you can do `@comment.destroy`, but it will not track who deleted it. Also, note, it's quite simple to develop a comment feature using Rails. It might be worth rolling your own solution -- for the experience, if nothing else.

Comment: Excellent comment. Yes it is true that I need to better structure my code. The gem isn't well instructed however the initial set up is clear and I had no trouble adding a voting system to it. As you said, `@comment.destroy` won't track who deleted it. How can I refer it to a user id so that it knows which user deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd suggest you refactor your `can_be_deleted_by?` method, and, as I mentioned in my comment, because the gem isn't well documented or supported, it might be worth rolling your own solution (or [looking for another gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_comments)).

You should consider [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) for managing authorization rules, but here's a simple fix for your `can_be_deleted_by?` method:

```
def can_be_deleted_by?(user)
  [can_be_etc?, can_be_etc_etc?].all?
end

def can_be_etc?
end

def can_be_etc_etc?
end
```

It's still a sketchy structure, but it's infinitely better than throwing all of that logic into a single method.

#### Answer to your question

You'll likely have to dig through source code for the gem because the docs are quite lacking. One way, if they don't provide native support for it:

add `default_scope` or named [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) and use to filter comments

```
def Comment
  # update with correct column (deleted_by is a guess)
  scope :active, -> { where(deleted_by: nil) }
end

# view
# also assuming you have direct access to comments
@article.comments.active.each [...]
```

If that becomes a struggle, as a last resort, you can add a `default_scope`, which will be applied every time comments are queried, and must be disabled manually (if you ever wanted to access deleted comments).

Comment: I'm going to follow your advice and try making my own commenting system or maybe using this [gem](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading).Thank you for taking the time to help me and for that I will check your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Cyzanfar probably a wise decision! Feel free to post another question if you get stuck.